# Unable to get the values from EditText fields in android

Tags: android-fragments

I have facebook integration done for my android app, now I have the FB login button also user can register for our application and login using his email id.
so I have 2 different ways to login.
Problem is that I m unable to get the values in the EditText field provided by user to login.
I m able to get the value in registeration page but not in the login page.
But if I remove all the codes used for FB integration it works fine..
I have a fragment activity.
Please help and let me know if any info needed..

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        try {
            Log.i("TAG", "Inside Hash Key");
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.package", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash :", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();

    } else {

        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }
    try {
        Log.i("TAG", "Inside Hash Key");
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.package", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash :", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

This is what I have in my oncreate.

Comment: In this case, you should make a update that contain the codes used for FB integration, that will be better for anyone to solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry... I have updated now..